# How do I find out what wifi chipset my phone has?

Tags: wi-fi, hardware, system-info

I've got LG Optimus One phone (model LG-P500h). How do I find out what wifi chipset my phone has? Is there a general mechanism that will work for all phones?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but...This is an _excellent_ example of the kind of questions we like here. It's asking how solve a particular problem ***and*** has applicability for future readers.

Comment: You can see the chipset model under 'Device' in CPU-Z application. Type that in Google and see if it gets you to a specification page that also specifies 'WiFi' connectivity.

Comment: I just run: getprop | grep connectivity
Which outputs:                       [ro.connectivity.chiptype]: [bcm43xx]                  [ro.connectivity.sub_chiptype]: [bcm4359]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well without some specialized program, there's always `dmesg`.

Turn on wifi, then run `dmesg` in a terminal/`adb shell`/ConnectBot. Towards the end of the file you'll see debug statements about your wireless.

`dmesg | grep -i lan` can be useful if you have busybox installed.

I get lines like this:

```
TIWLAN: 1251 PG 1.2
tiwlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

The first one isn't interesting on its own, but the second one screams "network adapter" due to driver naming convention for network adapters. "tiwlan0" is closer to OpenBSD's naming convention than Linux's (Linux native drivers would just call it wlan0) but...not unexpected.

A few web searches later - and yep, it's a [TI wireless chip](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ti%20wlan%201251).

Answer (score 2):

The sure fire method that will work for any phone is to crack open the case, write down the name and part number of the chips, and then research them individually.  That can be pretty intensive though, not to mention that you might damage your phone in the process.  Manufacturers typically do not publish the parts list for their products.  The product spec sheet may contain the CPU type (a Qualcomm MSM7227 in the case of your phone).  They may also list the GPU (Qualcomm Adreno 200 for your LG Optimus One P500).  No guarantee on that though.

The folks over at [isuppli.com](http://www.isuppli.com/Pages/Home.aspx) teardown hardware and inventory the parts.  Most of their reports you have to pay for, but some get published for free.

Most handsets use a chip from Texas Instruments, Broadcom, Royal Philips Electronics, or Atheros Communications.  Using those chip maker names as a filter may help you to zero in on the particular chip in your handset.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the `dmesg` command in a terminal emulator and scrolled until I found anything named `bcm432x...` and `wlan`. Think thats it. I have lg p500.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wi Mark BenchMark Receptor from google play.
OR
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQtxZ4MbaFA

Comment: Could you include some more details please? For one, where to find that app you mention (a link would be most helpful). And secondly: What is that Youtube link for? Not everybody can access it (e.g. because of firewalls or Chinese walls), so a few explanatory words should accompany it. In this context, also remember that links might die (and Youtube videos taken offline for "copyright" issues etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a phone yet whose wifi chipset it has detected.

Answer (score -1):

I simply googled "what chipset is in galaxy j100" (my phone) done some reading and got answer..... fyi this one has chipset by marvell...
And yours, the LG has a Qualcomm msm 7227

Comment: I've deleted the duplicate answer you posted earlier. In future, if you want to add more information to your answer, you can edit it using the **edit** link. Don't just post a second answer, as that will lead to confusion.